# how to optimize this three table query in mysql?

Tags: mysql

[please click to see the image to help make query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1CPN.png)

```
customer
cus_ID  name
1       jon
2      maik

order
rec_ID  cus_ID  amount
1         1      100
2         1      100
3         1      100
4         1      100
5         2      150
6         2       50

payment
pay_ID  cus_ID  amount
1          1    100
2          1    100
3          1    50
4          2    50

OUTPUT Need

name    order_amount    pay_amount
jon         400           250
maik        200            50
```

this is my three table how can i get output in mysql query. i will try this code

```
SELECT c.name
     , SUM(o.amount) oamount
     , SUM(p.amount) pamount 
  FROM customer c
  JOIN `order` o 
    ON o.cus_ID = c.cus_ID
  JOIN payment p 
    ON p.cus_ID = c.cus_ID 
 GROUP 
    BY c.cus_ID
```

but that not make perfect result please help to solved this

Comment: Please include necessary code, DDL, sample data to your question. Images don't really help

Comment: i insert sample data in post if possible please help to solve this query

Comment: @mmm, I agree about not using images, but as a newbie, they will learn...  Also, Nazmul, click on Help -> Tour for site eitquette to help you in the future too.

Comment: @DRapp didn't want to be impolite, too. It's just easier to help people if they include the things needed to answer directly into their question.

Comment: Note that order is a reserved word in MySQL - making it a poor choice as a table/column identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are doing ALL customers, and to prevent false Cartesian products from one table having more records than another per order / payment tables, create your joins to SUBQUERIES per respective grouped only on the customer ID.

I have done LEFT-JOIN to the sub queries JUST IN CASE there are entries where either no payment OR no order prevents the record from being included.  No need for a final group by because each customer record will be only one, and since the underlying subqueries are ALSO grouped by customer id, there would at MOST be one record per sub-query and never result in a Cartesian set.

```
SELECT 
      customer.name, 
      COALESCE( sumOrder.TotalOrders, 0 ) AS oamount, 
      COALESCE( sumPay.TotalPay, 0 ) AS pamount 
   FROM 
      customer 
         LEFT JOIN 
         ( select o.cus_id,
                  sum( o.amount ) as TotalOrders
              from 
                 order o 
              group by
                 o.cus_id ) sumOrder
            ON customer.cus_ID = sumOrder.cus_ID 
         LEFT JOIN 
         ( select p.cus_id,
                  sum( p.amount ) as TotalPay
              from 
                 payment p
              group by
                 p.cus_id ) sumPay
            ON customer.cus_ID = sumPay.cus_ID
```

Comment: thank you DRapp, it's working

Comment: @nazmul, great... As a newbie, take a look at Help -> Tour for site etiquette and marking questions as solved so others know what worked searching for similar problems,or still open needing other answers.